Which is greater? $\;50^{99}$ or $99!\;?$

Which is greater? $\;50^{99}$ or $99!\;?$

My attempt:
$99!=99\cdot98\ldots2\cdot1=$
$=(50+49)(50+48)\ldots 50\ldots(50-48)(50-49)=$
$=(50^2-49^2)(50^2-48^2)\ldots(50^2-1^2)50\qquad(1)$
Now, $50^2-49^2<50^2$, $50^2-48^2<50^2$,$\ldots$, $50^2-1^2<50^2$
Multiplying these $49$ inequalities together, we get
$(50^2-49^2)(50^2-48^2)\ldots(50^2-1^2)<(50^2)^{49}=50^{98}$
Multiplying both sides by $50$, we get
$(50^2-49^2)(50^2-48^2)\ldots(50^2-1^2)50<50^{99}$
Using $(1)$, we get $99!<50^{99}$.

What's your question?

Consider the AM / GM inequality for a briefer proof.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532830/prove-n-n-2n-by-induction
